# given a pixel and gaussian filter, apply gaussian blur

Tags: python

I'm trying to apply a gaussian filter to an image. My filter is a n by n square maxtrix represented as list of list. I've converted my image into 3 separate 2d arrays of R, G and B so that calling `B[x][y]` would give me the blue value of that pixel at x,y.

I'm having a difficult time thinking of a way of applying the blur. For example, if I have the filter `[[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]`, the blurred result at `B[x][y]` should be

```
1*B[x-1][y-1] + 1*B[x-1][y] + 1*B[x-1][y+1] +
1*B[x][y-1] + 1*B[x][y] + 1* B[x][y+1] +
1*B[x+1][y-1] + 1*R[x+1][y] + 1*B[x+1][y+1]
```

I'm think of traversing each of the color 2d array (R, G, and B) using a nested loop, but I don't know what to do from that point since the value of x and y is changing at each location.

Given a red/ green/ blue pixel at x,y, how would I apply a gaussian filter of size n x n onto that pixel?

Comment: You should convert your matrix into a numpy array. This is the typical data structure for handling such data in Python. That way, you can make use of Numpy's vectorized operations to speed up the operation. Do not use loops in Python if possible for this sort of task, unless it is a requirement for homework assignment. Furthermore, use scipy for the filtering, or OpenCV (both operate on numpy arrays). These are libraries designed for such operations.

Comment: If you wish to avoid the libs, to apply gaussian blur to a pixel, simply compute the filter weights for each pixel in the window, then multiply them with the corresponding pixel values (single channel) for a window centered at a pixel (x, y), and sum the result. That will be the value for B(x, y). To handle the pixels at the boundary, you might have to decide of the boundary interpolation scheme, for e.g., duplicating the row/col at the boundary, extending the boundary and setting the new pixels to zero, or replicating the pixels from the opposite boundary (i.e., rollover/cyclical boundary).

Answer (score -1):

Start here: http://campar.in.tum.de/twiki/pub/Chair/TeachingSs04ImageSeg/VL_Segmentierung_kap8.pdf

Adjusting variables in the equation will greatly affect the sharpness of edges that you see.

Answer (score -1):

You should make a copy of the image pixel plane to use as the unchanged original as you compute each new pixel:

```
def blur( P ):
    T = list( P )
    for x ...
        P[x][y] = 1*T[x-1][y-1] + 1*T[x-1][y] + 1*T[x-1][y+1] +
           1*T[x][y-1] + 1*T[x][y] + 1* T[x][y+1] +
           1*T[x+1][y-1] + 1*T[x+1][y] + 1*T[x+1][y+1]
```

Comment: Currently, I'm not really sure how to get each value for both the filter and pixel. If I loop through the filter, I get the filter value correctly, but no way of getting the pixel value, vice versa.

Answer (score -1):

Pillow will do this for you. http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/ImageFilter.html
If your goal is to get the gaussian blur done and not to do it yourself.
Also other image ops in there.